# create column on dataframe that shows largest since in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pivot-table

What if I have the dictionary below:

```py
dict = {Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:00:00'): {'A': 12, 'B': 10}, 
        Timestamp('2010-02-01 00:00:00'): {'A': 5, 'B': 14},
        Timestamp('2010-03-01 00:00:00'): {'A': 2, 'B': 8},
        Timestamp('2010-04-01 00:00:00'): {'A': 11, 'B': 16}}
```

I make it a dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict)
```

What I want to do is create a column on this dataframe that shows, for the most recent timestamp `'2010-04-01 00:00:00'` that the numbers for A and B are the highest since when? If its a record, I want it to say record.

For this most recent timestamp `'2010-04-01 00:00:00'`, a column needs to be added that, for row A, says its the highest since `'2010-02-01 00:00:00'` and for row B, says its a record high.

I tried to display this as an actual dataframe, but the formatting gets messed up.

In real life, I have created a pivottable that has dates as the columns and the rows are indexed based on hundreds of names. Under each column are numbers. I need to be able to glance at a row at the end that tells me if numbers under the most current date are the highest since when.

Answer (score 1):

*Assumption*: Value in column for last date is larger than a value in one previous date column *at least once* (i.e. `highest since ...` or `record high`). If the value can also be `record low` (i.e. never larger than any previous value, use the version at the bottom of this A).

One approach could be as follows.

```
# N.B. don't call a variable `dict`; 
# doing so overwrites funcionality of `dict` as built-in mapping type
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)

df['eval_last'] = df.iloc[:,:-1].le(df.iloc[:,-1], axis=0)\
                       .cumsum(axis=1).eq(1).idxmax(axis=1)

df['eval_last'] = np.where(df['eval_last'].eq(df.columns[0]), 
                           'record high', 'highest since ' + 
                           df['eval_last'][0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

print(df['eval_last'])

A    highest since 2010-02-01 00:00:00
B                          record high
Name: eval_last, dtype: object
```

**Explanation**

- Select from `df` all columns except last and evaluate [`df.le`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.le.html) with last column as compared "other" along `axis=0`. At this stage, we are working with this result:

```
   2010-01-01  2010-02-01  2010-03-01
A       False        True        True
B        True        True        True
```

- Next, chain [`df.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) with `axis=1`. In the result, the first `True` in the row will get `1`. I.e.:

```
   2010-01-01  2010-02-01  2010-03-01
A           0           1           2
B           1           2           3
```

- Now, we use [`df.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) to check where the rows equal `1`, and add [`df.idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) along `axis=1` to retrieve the correct column name, and we assign this result to the new column:

```
print(df['eval_last'])
A   2010-02-01
B   2010-01-01
Name: eval_last, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

- Finally, we use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to change these datatimes into `'highest since ...'` or `'record high'`, depending on the evaluation of `df['eval_last'].eq(df.columns[0])`, i.e. whether or not the date found equals the first date in your columns.

---

**Approach for handling `record low` possibility**

```
# adding `C` as copy of `B`, except for last val: `2` (being < all prev vals)
my_dict = {Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:00:00'): {'A': 12, 'B': 10, 'C':10}, 
           Timestamp('2010-02-01 00:00:00'): {'A': 5, 'B': 14, 'C': 14},
           Timestamp('2010-03-01 00:00:00'): {'A': 2, 'B': 8, 'C':8},
           Timestamp('2010-04-01 00:00:00'): {'A': 11, 'B': 16, 'C':2}}

df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)

m = df.iloc[:,:-1].le(df.iloc[:,-1], axis=0)\
                       .cumsum(axis=1).eq(1)

df['eval_last'] = m[m.any(axis=1)].idxmax(axis=1)

condlist = [df['eval_last'].isnull(),
            df['eval_last'].eq(df.columns[0])]

choicelist = ['record low',
              'record high']
df['eval_last'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default=
                            df['eval_last'][0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

print(df['eval_last'])

A    2010-02-01 00:00:00
B            record high
C             record low
Name: eval_last, dtype: object
```

**Explanation**

- So, in this version, we are checking `idxmax` only for the rows that have at least one `True` value based on `df.iloc[:,:-1].le(df.iloc[:,-1], axis=0).cumsum(axis=1).eq(1)`. The rows passed by will get `NaT` values (appropriate for `C` here). I.e. we get column `eval_last` as follows at this stage:

```
A   2010-02-01
B   2010-01-01
C          NaT
Name: eval_last, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

- Next, we use `np.select` rather than `np.where`, and evaluate as follows:

1. Check for `NaN` values (`condlist[0]`), we need "record low" here (`choicelist[0]`).
2. Check equal to first col (`condlist[1]`), we need "record high" here (`choicelist[1]`).
3. If both evaluate to `False`, we use the `default` inside `np.select` for "highest since ...".

Comment: Thank you. I will evaluate this approach and try it out.